# updating score in card game

Tags: python, playing-cards

I am a total beginner with python.

I need help updating the score of a card game.

The scoring works as follows:

**Player A or B has a pair:**  score += 1
**Player A asks Player B (vice versa) for a card and that player has it:**  score += 1
**Player B doesn't have it, Player A has to draw a card. If there is pair after draw:** score += 2

I have the logic down but I don't really know how to connect it together.

I tried manually adding the scores in my functions, but it get's messy and complicated :(

I assume I would have to make a new function for the score and call them in my other functions?

I would appreciate the guidance,

Thank-you!

Comment: Please post the code you already have so we can (a) better understand what you are trying to achieve and (b) help you without having to rewrite everything you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to get you started:

```
class Player:
  def hasPair(self):
    haveIt = False
    #write logic here to see if you have it
    return haveIt
  def hasCard(self,card):
    haveIt = False
    #write logic here to see if this player has the card
    return haveIt
  def drawCard(self):
    #write logic here
    pass
  def ask(self,player,card):
    return player.hasCard(card)
  def increment_score(self,by=1):
    self.score += by

def updateScores(a,b,card):        
  if a.hasPair(): a.increment_score()
  if b.hasPair(): b.increment_score()
  if a.ask(b,card): 
    a.increment_score()
  else:
    a.drawCard()
    if a.hasPair(): a.increment_score(2)
  if b.ask(a,card):
    b.increment_score()
  else:
    b.drawCard()
    if b.hasPair(): b.increment_score(2)
```